# How can I get a list of my projects dependencies in a flattened form using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I know that Gradle has the excellent `dependencies` task that lists out all dependencies for a project. However, it returns them in a tree listing.

I would like to get a list of all my dependencies as they are resolved in just a flat list. Similar to how the Maven dependency plugin `list` goal behaves.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a short task that meets that need:

```
task('dependenciesList') <<  {
    println "Compile dependencies"
    def selectedDeps = project.configurations.compile.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { dep ->
        "${dep.selected}"
    }
    selectedDeps.unique().sort().each { println it}
}
```

The third line is the interesting part. You need to get the configuration you care about (compile) then instead of getting dependencies there, the `incoming.resolutionResult` will provide the resolved values and versions.

---

`<<` was removed in Gradle 5. To make the task work in Gradle 5 and later versions, remove `<<` and use `doLast { }` instead. Also, use `runtimeClasspath` or `compileClasspath` for the configuration instead of `compile`:

```
task('dependenciesList') {
    doLast {
        println "Compile dependencies"
        def selectedDeps = project.configurations.compileClasspath.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { dep ->
            "${dep.selected}"
        }
        selectedDeps.unique().sort().each { println it}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Without modifying the build, flatten the tree using sed, sort, and uniq as follows:

```
$ gradle dependencies | sed 's/^.* //' | sort | uniq
```

Alternatively, with slightly tighter `sed` matching:

```bash
./gradlew dependencies \
  | sed -n 's/.*--- \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' \
  | grep -v "^project$" \
  | sort \
  | uniq
```

Comment: Just for completeness, `sort -u` does the same thing as `sort | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers already supplied.

Finally I complete it by a more standard way:

```
project.gradle.addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies dependencies) {}
    
    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies dependencies) {
        dependencies.resolutionResult.allComponents.each { select ->
            println "selected component: ${select} " + select.selectionReason
        }
    }
})
```

`Project implementation` will also be resolved in this way, and the final selected component version will be resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that simplifies things if you are using Android Studio or Intellij. Open the Project view and expand External Libraries. From here, select all Gradle ones and copy/paste to a text file. The output should look like this:

```
...
Gradle: androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0@aar
Gradle: androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.5.3@aar
Gradle: androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.5.3@aar
...
```

I suspect this corresponds to the `compileClasspath` Gradle configuration, but I can't be certain.