# Gradle equivalent to maven dependency:list

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

Maven provides a way to show a list of all resolved dependencies with [`mvn dependency:list`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html):

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO]    javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:com:compile
[INFO]    javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
```

Gradle's dependency report is in a tree structure, which makes it difficult to clearly see version is finally used.

Is there a command or something that gives me this list of the resolved dependencies without the tree structure?

Comment: Check out https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/gradle-tricks-tracking-down-not-expected-transitive-dependencies/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of my projects dependencies in a flattened form using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641631/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-my-projects-dependencies-in-a-flattened-form-using-gradl)

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the followin at the command line (in your gradle project dir)

```
gradle tasks
```

You'll see the following in the list

```
Help tasks
----------
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'xyz'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'xyz'
```

More info [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:listing_buildscript_dependencies)

Comment: Neither of these do quite what is being asked, however.  The "dependencies" task is more equivalent to `mvn dependency:tree`, which gives the result in a tree structure (something the question asker specifically specified they didn't want).