# Find all dependencies and their resolved versions in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am looking for a way to display all the dependencies and their resolved versions in a Gradle project. I want the result to be flat.

Gradle has the `dependencies` task which prints the dependency tree, however, it is not flat and hard to read. For e.g. logback-classic has the following dependency tree.

```
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
```

Instead of this tree structure, I want the result to be following(dependencies with their resolved versions):

```
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
```

This way it would be easy for me to find out the vulnerable libraries(for e.g. log4j), and it would also give me insights on dependent jars even if I don't directly use them.

Comment: looks like you are looking for Maven equivalent of dependency:list. Found a similar question here but unfortunately no answer for this yet - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636952/gradle-equivalent-to-maven-dependencylist